# Не удается правильно размножить время в цикле

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь размножить время в цикле, начиная с текущего:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dt = new Date();
var currentMinutes = dt.getMinutes();
var currentSeconds = dt.getSeconds();
for (i = 1; i <= 130; i++) {
    var minutesOfCreating = currentMinutes;
    var secondsOfCreating = currentSeconds*1+i*1;
    if(secondsOfCreating > 59) {
        var secondsOfCreating = secondsOfCreating*1-60*1;
        var minutesOfCreating = minutesOfCreating*1+1*1;
    }
    var minutesOfCreating = minutesOfCreating.toString();
    var secondsOfCreating = secondsOfCreating.toString();
    if(secondsOfCreating.length == 1) {
        var secondsOfCreating = '0'+secondsOfCreating;
    }
    if(minutesOfCreating.length == 1) {
        var minutesOfCreating = '0'+minutesOfCreating;
    }
    console.log(minutesOfCreating+secondsOfCreating);
}
</script>
```

Если значение секунды в цикле больше 59 тогда нужно отминусовать 60, а к минуте добавить единицу. Но как видно в консоле данное правило срабатывает лишь первый раз, второй раз почему то отминусовать 60 и соответственно прибавить единицу к минуте не удается.

В чем загвоздка?

---

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**

Выяснил что перед условием `if(secondsOfCreating > 59)` можно добавить еще условие:

```
if(secondsOfCreating > 119) {
    var secondsOfCreating = secondsOfCreating*1-120*1;
    var minutesOfCreating = minutesOfCreating*1+2*1;
}
```

Тогда проблема решается. Но это если заранее известно что на входе именно 130 итераций, т.е. они охватывают 2 целые минуты и часть третьей. А как быть если число итераций может быть любое?

Теоретически я могу взять количество целых минут и соответственно узнать сколько мне нужно таких условий:

```
for (i = 1; i <= range; i++) {
    var number = Math.floor(range/60);
```

Но как потом в цикле "размножить" эти условия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я совсем не понимаю, почему вы не хотите использовать встроенные средства языка для работы со временем. Ведь `Date` из коробки умеет делать смещение по времени.

В коде это может выглядеть как-то так:

```
// Эта функция добавляет ведущие нули там, где это нужно.
var f = function(n) { 
    return (n < 10) ? ('0' + n) : ('' + n);
};

var dt = new Date();
for (var i = 1; i <= 130; i++) {
    // Добавляем смещение в одну секунду к временной метке.
    dt = new Date(dt.getTime() + 1000);
    // Выводим результат в формате "минуты":"секунды".
    console.log(f(dt.getMinutes())+':'+f(dt.getSeconds()));
}
```

Comment: Почему вы решили что я "не хочу". Я впервые вижу такие "средства"

Answer (score 1):

Ну так все просто и правильно, посмотрите на эту строчку и подставьте в нее 121:

```
if(secondsOfCreating > 59) {
    var secondsOfCreating = secondsOfCreating*1-60*1;
    var minutesOfCreating = minutesOfCreating*1+1*1;
}
```

Путем простой математики получаем: `121 - 60 = 61` И чем дальше, тем сложнее)) Что будет, если итерация перейдет за тысячу?

Вам нужно использовать другой подход, вычислять остатки и деление.

```
if(secondsOfCreating > 59) {
    var secondsOfCreating = Number(secondsOfCreating) % 60;
    var minutesOfCreating = Number(minutesOfCreating) + Math.floor(Number(secondsOfCreating) / 60);
}
```

Тогда код будет отрабатывать правильно.

Comment: Отсчет должен начинатся от текущего времени а не от первой секунды. А в "другом подходе" у вас минута все же не увеличивается на единицу

Comment: @stckvrw, если кто-то учится и использует для того велосипеды, я не против, я просто укажу ошибку без оптимизации. Но Вы можете упростить себе жизнь, если познакомитесь с хоть какой-то [документацией по языку](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript) и научитесь сначала искать там нужные инструменты.

К примеру, [для даты в документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) вы уже найдете функции получения и установки компонентов. Впрочем, дописывать нет смысла, т.к. это сделал DmitriySimushev в своем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Почему не происходит? Происходит.

К примеру, для i = 130 к секундам добавляется 130, а потом вычитается 60. Один раз.

Вероятно, вам лучше не добавлять `i` к начальному значению - а добавлять `1` к предыдущему вычисленному значению.

Comment: Я как раз и написал что первый раз вычитывается 60, а второй и последующие разы почему то нет

Comment: @stckvrw так почему нет-то? На каждый итерации оно вычитается.

Comment: @stckvrw в голове. В таких простых случаях этого достаточно.

Comment: Так вы реально проверьте, в браузере. У меня идёт например 58, 59, потом 00, 01. Это при пересечении 59 первый раз. Но второй раз когда дходит до 59, то дальше идёт 60, 61 и т.д.

Comment: @stckvrw совершенно верно. Я вам даже написал почему так происходит.

Comment: Ничего не понял... Вы написали что к секундам добавляется 130. К секундам добавляется сначало 1, потом 2, потом 3 и т.д. А 60 вычитывается когда сумма превышает 59. И что "происходит" тоже не понял

Comment: @stckvrw К секундам добавляется сначала 1, потом 2, потом 3 и т.д., в добавляется 130.

Comment: @stckvrw откройте в вашем любимом браузере отладчик javascript да пройдитесь уже по шагам!